# Any built-in filtering option for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is it possible to attach filters (I'm not sure about the name of this) to EditTexts, so that if the user types in something in the wrong manner, than a warning of some sort pops up on the EditText?

For example: there's an EditText on a form and it must be filled. So until it's empty, some warning is displayed in it, showing that it's a required field on the form.

I've seen similar behaviour on EditTexts all around Android, so I guess there's a built-in feature for this, but I can't find it. Could somebody help me out please?

Target Android version is 3.0 and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add a [**TextWatcher**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and react accordingly in your implementation of `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)`. Just check if `s` is empty or not, or if it's correct or not.

You can implement [**filters**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) also, but those are usually to *prevent* the user to entering wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `android:inputType` attribute of `EditText` in xml. For example `android:inputType="textEmailAddress|number|phone"` and other stuff.
But for checking emptiness I can't suggest anything but `if (editText.getText().length() > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add filter using code with Text watcher event. When you type any think on Edit Text the text watcher event is execute then we are able to check the type text in edit text if condition is false then you should show popup . I am showing a example for filtering in list view using edit text with the help of text watcher event you should you it for filtering in edittext.

ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            fillMaps.clear();
            textlength = ed.getText().length();
            for (int i = 0; i < countryName.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= countryName[i].length()) {
                    if (ed.getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) countryName[i].subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("flag", "" + imageId[i]);
                        map.put("country", countryName[i].toString());
                        map.put("capital", capitalName[i].toString());
                        map.put("countrytime",
                                convertDateTimeToGMT(
                                        GMTplusMinusInMillisecond[i],
                                        plusMinus[i]));
                        map.put("GMT", GMTplusMinus[i].toString());

                        fillMaps.add(map);
                    }
                }
            }
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    WorldClockActivity.this, fillMaps, R.layout.grid_item,
                    from, to);
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
            // lv1.setAdapter(new
            // ArrayAdapter<String>(WorldClockActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            // , arr_sort));

        }
    });
```